# sum/product combination of random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, self-learning

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables. If I am asked about the distribution of random variable $XY+Y$, is it ok if I compute $XY$ first and then add the result to $Y$ (via convolution, or otherwise), or I lose 'independence' here?

If so, I should I proceed. Thanks for your insights.

Comment: In general $XY$ and $Y$ will not be independent so convolution does not work. Btw, if you have the skills to find the distribution of $XY$ when $X$ and $Y$ are independent. then you have also the skills of finding the distribution of $ZY$ for $Z=X+1$. Note that also $Z$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I immediately saw that I can factor and say (X+1)Y. My question is, if XY and Y are not independent and convolution wouldn't work, how should the next step look like?